# How do I create a Linux N6 (with GPU) VM on Azure for Deep Learning applications?

Tags: linux, azure, virtual-machine, gpu, azure-dsvm

When I try to do new Ubuntu Compute VM in East US or South Central US (the two with advertised GPU support), there is no option to select N6.

The only way to get N6 VM is to use the "Deep Learning toolkit for the DSVM" option, which is a Windows VM.

Is it possible to create a Linux N6 VM on Azure?  If so, how?

Comment: have you tried powershell?

Comment: is that a vm option?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-ps-create

Comment: I'll try it.  thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is to select "HDD" instead of the default SSD for disk type. Then the NC* series will show.

Comment: those vm's use hdd for OS disk? for real?

Comment: yep, for reasons I don't understand

Comment: the ui is quite un-intuitive here.  it's making the user go through a maze where the path ahead is unknown.  i wonder if there is a way to give them that feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft recently released a new version of the Data Science Virtual Machine for Linux (Ubuntu) edition on Azure with several popular deep learning tools pre-installed that you can use on either NC-Series GPU Azure VM or any CPU only VM.

More info:

http://aka.ms/dsvm/ubuntu

http://aka.ms/dsvm/ubuntu/docs

Comment: this looks like it would save some setup time.  thanks for pointing it out.